# SingleOrDefault throws "Sequence contains more than one element" when querying by primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am running into a funky issue, where `.SingleOrDefaultAsync` is throwing an error when I don't expect it to.  I have table `Thing`, with primary key of `varchar` `ThingId`.

I have code similar to as follows:

```
IDbSet<Thing> Things;  // initialized by dependency injection
...

public async Task<Thing> FindThingById(string thingId)
{
    return await Things.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.ThingId == thingId).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Any thoughts on how this could be returning multiple results and thus throwing an exception saying `'Sequence contains more than one element'`??

When I run a SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM Things where ThingId = '1234'
```

I get one result as expected.

Edit (calling code):

```
public sealed partial class ThingDetailsManager : IThingDetailsManager
    {
        private readonly IThingRepository _thingRepository;
        private readonly IThingDetailsSerializer _thingDetailsSerializer;

        public async Task<ThingDetails> FetchThingDetails(string thingId)
        {
            var thing = await _orderRepository.FindThingById(thingId).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (thing == null)
                return null;

            var thingDetails = _thingDetailsSerializer.Deserialize(thing.ThingDetails);
            thingDetails.SetThingId(thingId);

            return thingDetails;
        }
    }
```

Comment: well, there are multiple elements returned with the specified id hence the exception. are you expecting only 1 element to be returned or a set of elements but only want to return the first one found?

Comment: How are you populating `Things` in .Net? As @Aominè stated, there are clearly more than 1 elements with the same ID. If you change `SingleOrDefault` to `FirstOrDefault`, I bet it works. Obviously, that's not what you're looking for, but lacking an example dataset, i can only assume you have duplicate IDs in the .Net dataset.

Comment: Change your method to return all items (Where, ToArray) and see what are those multiple elements, that will give you a clue.

Comment: Are you showing your actual code ?  Maybe you can show actual code?
is your primary key ("ThingId") a string (nvarchar)?

Comment: @Aominè  maybe I'm not following, but Things is a DbSet backed by Entity Framework.  In the SQL table, there is only one element per ThingId.

Comment: @DaniDev, ThingId is a string

Comment: since we can't see all your actual code (EF dbSet database, etc.) then it would be impossible to trouble shoot, but you should follow the advise and break down your query. use first or default or maybe even return a list  . maybe don't run it as async until you know its running right.

Comment: @DaniDev are you looking for the schema?  there isn't much more c# code to show.

Comment: Download LINQPad and try using `Where` instead of `SingleOrDefault` to see what is being returned. (`Things.Where(o => o.ThingId == thingId).Dump()`).

Comment: I should also specify that this is intermittent.  It happens infrequently, but when it does it causes pretty big issues.

Comment: "this is intermittent. It happens infrequently"   Bingo!   that means it is almost certainly tied to the async call.  I bet a bunch it wont happen at all if you don't use async/await

Comment: Any reason why?

Comment: can you show the code where you calling this method?

Comment: @DaniDev just added an edit

Comment: I don't know that I can tell you specifically why? but, since  as you say it happens infrequently and if you are certain that the data does not allow for duplicate thingIDs  (????)  then you are certain that you are getting duplicate records then it must mean that somehow while using TAP and initiating another thread  you are contaminating your result set?

Comment: Another  thing of note Is from the additional code posted it doesn't appear that you are gaining any benefit by using TAP await /async pattern.